# SQL - update table from another table - syntax error

Tags: sql, sql-update

I have two SQL tables:

```
matches (columns are hometeam, awayteam, id, gameweek)
teams (columns are teamcode, teamname)
```

`matches.hometeam` and `matches.awayteam` consist of integers that correspond to integers in `teams.teamcode`. I am trying to get `matches.hometeam` and `matches.awayteam` to update to strings that are taken from corresponding strings in `teams.teamname`. If that is impossible, then I need to create a new table as described.

I have tried the below code, but it produces a syntax error on the penultimate two lines (error 1064 (42000)). I can't figure out why.

```
UPDATE matches
SET matches.hometeam = teams.teamname
FROM matches
INNER JOIN teams
ON (matches.hometeam = teams.teamcode);
```

Comment: _"matches.hometeam ... consist of integers"_, _"trying to get matches.hometeam ... to update to strings"_ - You can't put a string into an integer column

Comment: Do you have any foreign or primary keys? Do you care about the names of the columns at the end of the process? Are you certain that you _should_ do the thing that you're _trying_ to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error 1064 is a MySQL error.  If you are using MySQL, the correct syntax is:

```
UPDATE matches m JOIN
       teams t
       ON m.hometeam = t.teamcode
    SET m.hometeam = t.teamname;
```

However, this will not really work.  What you need to do is add ids:

```
alter table matches add hometeamcode int;
```

And then do:

```
UPDATE matches m JOIN
       teams t
       ON m.hometeam = t.teamcode
    SET m.hometeamcode = t.teamname;
```

EDIT:

I think I misunderstood the whole situation.  Your data model is totally correct.  The `matches` table should have the integer codes, referring to the rows in `teams`.

You just need to write your query to get the names:

```
select m.*, th.teamname as hometeamname, ta.teamname as awayteamname
from matches m join
     team th
     on m.hometeam = th.teamcode join
     team ta
     on a.hometeam = ta.teamcode;
```

If you don't want to do the `join`, then encapsulate the logic in the view.

Comment: This shows the correct approach: Add a new column with the correct type, then set its value. The choice of name for the new column(s) is probably wrong; it should be `hometeam_name`, right? Rinse and repeat for the away teams.